# Click search button without button id, class name

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to click a search button to open a new page where I can search.
I am unable to click the search button as only button name is given in inspect element code.

```
button type="button" on click="window.location='Go?action=agent'" Search /button
```

I can't provide the URL as it will not work outside the office.

From below code I can login on page and I can go to the page where the search button is. After that I am stuck on that page.

```vb
Sub login_page()
    
    Dim IE App As Internet Explorer
    
    Dim IE Doc As Object
    
    'create a new instance of IE
    Set IE App = New Internet Explorer
    
    IE App.Visible = True
    
    IE App.navigate "URL"
    
    Do While IE App.Busy: Do Events: Loop
    
    Do Until IE App.ready State = READY STATE_COMPLETE: Do Events: Loop
    
    Set IE Doc = IE App.document
    
    With IE Doc.forms(0)
        .user.Value = "id"
        .Password.Value = "password"
        .submit
    End With

    IE App.navigate "hyperlink URL"
    
    Do While IE App.Busy: Do Events: Loop
    
    'Do Until IE App.ready State = READY STATE_COMPLETE: Do Events: Loop
    
    IE App.navigate "hyperlink URL"
    
    Do While IE App.Busy: Do Events: Loop
    
    IE App.navigate "hyperlink URL"
    
    Do While IE App.Busy: Do Events: Loop

    ieApp.document.getElementsById("go").Value = "123"
      
    With ieApp.document
        .getElementById("go").Value = "123"
    End With
    
    ieApp.document.parentWindow.getElementsbyid("go").Value = "123"
    
    ieApp.document.parentWindow.getElementbyid("go").Value = "123"
    
    ieApp.document.getElementById("go").Value = "123"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following where I directly run the onclick event javascript.

```
 ieApp.document.parentWindow.execScript "window.location='Go?action=agent'"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i have edit the code and tried the above code but its not working.

Comment: ie.document.querySelector("[onclick*='action=agent']").click 

with the above code geting run time error

so i have tried with below code. but still getting error.

Dim ie As HTMLInputElement
Dim button As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement 

ie.querySelector ("[onclick$='action=agent']")

button.Click

i have tried with the above code i can login but getting below debug error.

("Run time error '91'

Object variable or With block variable not set")
Please help with the full code. edit in my code.

Comment: getting error as : ("Run time error '91'

Object variable or With block variable not set")

Comment: do i need to declare what is ie in my code.    i have not declare anywhere in my code what is ie.....  as you can see i have declare Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer but not ie.document the i have written this code at the end ie.document.querySelector("[onclick*='action=agent']").click

Comment: still its not working i have update code as ieApp.document.querySelector("[onclick*='action=agent']").Click    ..... getting debug error as Run time error '424': and below that object required error..

Comment: try the following:   ieApp.document.parentWindow.execScript "window.location='Go?action=agent'"

Comment: hi to continue this now i want add value in text box then click on search button.but getting object error and object dosent suport this property error  please help. 
    
text box html code is : <input type="text" size="40" name="agent" id="go" value="">
            
search button code:     <button type="submit">Submit</button>